# Почему вылетает LoadException?

Tags: javafx, controller, java, исключения

При запуске jar-а на Windows 7 (на Windows 8 всё ОК) вылетает LoadException.
Для тестирования использовалась виртуалка с windows 7 на ней.
Использовалась среда IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1, java 1.8.0_25 (на ноуте и на виртуалке, виртуалка или др. комп - неважно). Судя по ошибке, по какой-то причине не находится контроллер VerbViewController.fxml, но почему - непонятно.

Нижеприведенный код отрабатывает корректно на Windows 8.1, но на Windows 7 не хочет. Выдает вот что:

```
for (final Button button_for_handle : this.getButtons()) {
    button_for_handle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            increaseClickCounter();
            if (!Player.getTurn()) {
                Player.getPlayer(0).setScoreForQuestion(button_for_handle.getText());
            }
            if (Player.getTurn()) {
                Player.getPlayer(1).setScoreForQuestion(button_for_handle.getText());
            }
            if (!PressedButtonId.contains(button_for_handle.getId())) {
                PressedButtonId.add(button_for_handle.getId());
            }
            try {
                GameApp.loadView("/game/view/VerbView.fxml");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

C:\MY GAME>java -jar Game2.jar
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/MY%20GAME/Game2.jar!/game/view/VerbView.fxml:13

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at game.GameApp.loadView(GameApp.java:20)
        at game.BoardViewController$1.handle(BoardViewController.java:162)
        at game.BoardViewController$1.handle(BoardViewController.java:149)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/29531133.run(Unknown S
ource)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at game.VerbViewController.getRandomVerb(VerbViewController.java:72)
        at game.VerbViewController.<init>(VerbViewController.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Un
known Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
        ... 35 more
```

Содержимое VerbView.fxml:

```
 <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" opacity="0.73" prefHeight="452.0" prefWidth="760.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="game.VerbViewController">
```

Содержимое метода loadView (для загрузки сцены):

```
public static void loadView(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(GameApp.class.getResource(fxmlPath));
    Pane pane = (Pane)loader.load();
    currentStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
}
```

Comment: Да, кстати, откомпилированную программу пробовали запускать в разных системах? Такие же ошибки пишет в лог?

Answer (score 3):

Пробовали указывать относительный путь вручную для Вашего fxml? Да, и так-то приведенный Вами код и код эксепшена вообще ни о чем, кроме Вашего предположения, не говорит, по идее, должно все работать.

Попробуйте так:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/packageName/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

Попробуйте использовать один и тот же путь до исполняемого файла в разных системах, поищите закономерности разные.

Comment: охренеть!! заработало!! )))))))) Правда, перед этим ещё виртуалка вдруг внезапно стала падать(вот уж чего не ожидал я никогда от vmware). Поставил относительный путь и всё заработало... В качестве пути использовал packagename/file.fxml.

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov, рад, что все получилось! :)

Answer (score 0):

А можете прислать структуру в jar-файле, где находится GameApp.class и VerbView.fxml?

Потому что если Вы вызывается через такую конструкцию

```
loader.setLocation(GameApp.class.getResource(fxmlPath));
```

то fxmlPath должен лежать рядом с GameApp.class

А еще можно вызывать в 1 строку

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(GameApp.class.getResource(fxmlPath));
```